# How flexible is 'in' in Python e.g. if 'xxx' in yyy:

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

is there a meaningful difference between:

```
z='xxx'
if z in ['xxx', 'yyy']:
if 'xxx' or 'yyy' in z:
```

will 'in' allow a partial and split string match?

```
if 'xx yy' in 'xx zz yy':
```

I spent all day bug hunting and it boiled down to the above. Otherwise the code is line for line identical. Worst part is both scripts worked, I was just having a hell of a time consolidating them. Both other people's legacy code on legacy/partial data with limited documentation. I fixed it in the end, but these are my lingering questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value) The tl;dr is that `x or y in z` does not mean "is either x in z or y in z?" but rather "is x a truthy value, or is y in z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Crash

Yes, there is a meaningful difference

```
z='xxx'
z in ['xxx', 'yyy']
```

is checking if the list contains 'xxx' which it does

```
if 'xxx' or 'yyy' in z:
```

will always return True since non-emptystrings are truthy; ie
`if ('xxx'):` is True

You could re-write it more explicitly as

```
if 'xxx' or ('yyy' in z):
```

I believe what you'd be looking for is more like this:

```
if any([i in z for i in ['xxx', 'yyy']):
```

which checks if either 'xxx' or 'yyy' is in z

FWIW; there's also:

```
if all([i in z for i in ['xxx', 'yyy']):
```

---

regarding your question of

```
if 'xx yy' in 'xx zz yy':
```

that would only check for the exact string literal; if you wanted to look for both `xx` or `yy` there are a number of ways you could handle it but I would probably turn the first string into a lists and check the elements like this:

```
if all([i in 'xx zz yy' for i in 'xx yy'.split(" ")]):
```

which is the same as

```
if all([i in 'xx zz yy' for i in ['xx', 'yy']):
```

Comment: Thank You. I appreciate you being clear and thorough in your explanation.

Comment: @Crash glad that helps, if that's all please mark the question as answered.

Welcome to the community